# Struct in Class access Class Members

Tags: c#

since im new to C# im not sure if its possible to access a classes members from a structure in the class like this:

```
namespace Hello
{
  class Foo
  {
    public int cint0;
    private struct Struct7
    {
  public string str0;
      void Work()
      {
        str0 = "";
        cint0 = 22;//how to access cint0 from within the struct
      }
    }
  }
}
```

if there is a way to do it maybe someone can help

Comment: You need an instance of the class.

Comment: You should not be using a struct.

Answer (score 1):

The nested struct has proper access to the fields, even if they were private.  They are instance fields though hence you must access them off of an instance of `Foo`

```
void Work(Foo f) {
  f.cint0 = 22; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested struct inside of a class is a really bad idea,anyway, you need to a class instance to access a non-static members of a class like this:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
f.cint0 = 22
```